# One site with domain names - google search result

Tags: html, seo

I have one site and two domains which both are directed to same site. One of them I want to have "primary" because much better respond to content of site. So when someone will google for keywords, I want to see the site with the primary domain name. How can I do that?
thank you :)
jirka

Comment: Just to understand your question better, do you have two sites having similar content and you want one of them to be primary in your SERPs?

Comment: no - sorry - somehow I removed start of the text. I have one site with two domain names

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to redirect the user from one site to the other site without them looking at the change in the url.

But what you can do is, when the person opens the page from google. Make a javascript onload function which will redirect the person to your other domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Set up the second site to redirect to the first site instead of being a clone of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup canonical in your secondary site to point to the primary one. This signals google to attribute all SEO values to your primary site. If you do this, your secondary site can coexist and if people search specifically for secondary site, they can still land in your secondary site. When they search for keywords in google, google will show up your primary domain in SERPs as you have signalled to show up your primary domain. 
Example:

```
http://primarysite.com -> your primary site
http://secondarysite.com -> your secondary site
```

In your secondary site setup,

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://primarysite.com"/>
```

You can apply the same for http vs https as well. Hope this helps.